# Нужно ли закрывать от поисковиков файлы и архивы?

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы, robots.txt, яндекс-поиск

На сайте есть ссылки на скачиваемые файлы, например документ PDF и архив ZIP. Поисковики их определяют как отдельные страницы и индексируют (например "/files/example.pdf"). Нужно ли закрывать их от поиска, а также как и когда?

У меня на сайте один файл (.txt) яндекс удалил из поиска как малозначимую страницу, еще один подобный пока в поиске. Боюсь они будут расцениваться как НКС, поэтому закрою их в robots.txt. На будущее хочется разобраться как будет правильнее поступать с разными файлами.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не хотите что бы данные файлы были доступны(каким либо образом) в поиске, то необходимо скрывать. Не факт что боты смогут проанализировать эти документы и показывать их содержимое в запросе, но обычно скрывают. А в странице где эти файлы можно прочитать четко описывают данные файлы

Answer (score 0):

Вам лучше отдавать файл на скачивание.
После заголовков страницы, нужно дописать `readfile($file);`

Пример, кода:

```
function file_force_download($file) {
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    if (ob_get_level()) {
      ob_end_clean();
    }
    // заставляем браузер показать окно сохранения файла
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    // читаем файл и отправляем его пользователю
    readfile($file);
    exit;
  }
}
```